# "after end of resultset" error when trying to present data from a DB in a textfield in a JFrame

Tags: java, sql, search, textfield, resultset

I've got a method `find`  in the class `Driver`, that is to search entries in the database for the given word. The method looks as follows:

```
        public static ResultSet find (Connection conn, String word){
           ResultSet rs = null;
           PreparedStatement pst = null;
           try {
                pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from words where stem like '"+word+"'");
                                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                            }catch (Exception ex){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
                            }
                            return rs; 
                        }
```

Than I use this method in a JFrame class. When clicking a button `butSearch` it should display the found word in the text field `textFieldStem`.

```
 private void butSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
      ResultSet rs2 = Driver.find(conn, "frau");
        try {if (rs2.next()){
               tableWords.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));
               textFieldStem.setText(rs2.getString("stem"));



        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
        }}
        catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The thing is that, if I try to set text into the text field ->  `textFieldStem.setText(rs2.getString("stem"));` i get this error.

Yet if I try to display the result in the JTable `tablewords`
`tableWords.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));`, the problem does not accur. It displays the correct entry with all the data.

In my table `words` I've got three columns : `idword`, `articleid`, `stem`
The idea is to show only the word itself (which occurs in the colomn `stem` in my table) in the textfield `textFieldStem`, the data from the other colomns is not needed.

What is the trick?

the `DbUtils` class :

```
package net.proteanit.sql;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class DbUtils {
    public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

        // Get the column names
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
        columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
        }

        // Get all rows.
        Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

        while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<Object>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
        }

        rows.addElement(newRow);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
    }

    public static List<List<Object>> resultSetToNestedList(ResultSet rs, boolean includeColumnNames) {
    try {
        // To contain all rows.
        List<List<Object>> rows = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

        // Include column headers as first row if required
        if (includeColumnNames) {
        List<Object> columnNames = new ArrayList<Object>();

        // Get the column names
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
        }
        rows.add(columnNames);
        }

        // Get the data
        while (rs.next()) {
        List<Object> newRow = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            newRow.add(rs.getObject(i));
        }

        rows.add(newRow);
        }
        return rows;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
    }

    public static List<List<Object>> resultSetToNestedList(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        // To contain all rows.
        List<List<Object>> rows = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

        // Get the data
        while (rs.next()) {
        List<Object> newRow = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            newRow.add(rs.getObject(i));
        }

        rows.add(newRow);
        }
        return rows;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResultSet rs = new DummySimplestPlusMetaData();
    TableModel tm = DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);
    System.out.println(tm.getValueAt(0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, but I can say that your code in insecure for sql injection. Please take a look into this..http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement

Comment: instead of if(rs2.next()) use while(rs2.next()).

Comment: can you plz share the exception?

Comment: @Chandru while didn't change anything :(

Comment: @Chandru

exception ` java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set`

Comment: try to get the values from rs2 through index instead of column name

Comment: @Chandru using index also didn't help but...
after struggling for quite a while, i found a very simple but strange solution. if you first display data in the textfield and only then in the JFrame the error does not accur and it works, i just changed the order...
But i dont' get why, maybe you have any ideas?

Comment: @Diana Can you Show the Content of `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel`?

Comment: @Jean sure, i added it to the question description :)

Comment: I guess the issue is, if you call `if (rs2.next())` then cursor of the resultset moves to next position, If there is only on record in the result set then there is issue or else user will loose one data row. To overcome this, user must point back the cursor to initial position `rs.beforeFirst()` and for this, Resultset must be `Scroll Insensitive`.